# Use Universal-LPC-Spritesheet-Character-Generator in Android game

Tags: android, sprites

I am writing an Android game. I wonder if there is a possibility to use this sprite generator https://sanderfrenken.github.io/Universal-LPC-Spritesheet-Character-Generator/#?body=Body_color_light&head=Human_male_light&sex=male in my game?

Simply saying, I would like to have an Activity in which I would be able to use this:

1. some options from this website to choose from like body type, body color, hair, eyes, nose and beard;
2. character preview;
3. if user likes it then download character as png and use it later in a game.

It would be great to use this generator because there are many ways of character cusomization but if I cannot use this maybe would you advice me to use any other generator?

Then how to it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The license terms are explicitly stated on the page you link, as is the source of the sprites they used if you want to reimplement the same functionality. Where have you run into a specific obstacle that we can help you overcome?

Comment: @DMGregory I want to create the same functionality into my game. I want to create an activity in which there will be Android components with those options. I do not know how to use it maybe through REST api? You don't want me to use webview in my app and choose those options from website though.